# illegal activity on virtual server: ntp.client & smartctl.dump

Tags: security, ubuntu, server

We have a virtual webserver with ubuntu 12.04. Today we recived a message form the webhoster, because there are illegaly activities on this server.
I found bad code on different joomla installations and cleaned it. Now i have two proccess on this server, startet form our ftp-user with the following commands:

`/tmp/ntp.client -p9406 -d`

`/tmp/smartctl.dump -p3218 -d`

they used a lot cpu time and are similar and google says nothing to ntp.client or smartctl.dump

Can anybody say somthing about this processes. Can I kill them?
Thanks

PS: sorry for my english!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you installed it to /tmp yourself, get rid of it. And reinstall the server. Those two are easy to spot. You have no idea how many well hidden backdoors you already have on the system. Or better yet - get someone to install it for you and take care of it/secure it for you ...

edit: And see [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server) canonical question and the other linked questions on ServerFault, where this question actually belongs.

Comment: I killed this two tasks an nothing seems to be broken (as far I can see that). I will reinstall this server the next days... Thanks